# Why are my newly-installed ceiling tiles sagging?

Tags: ceiling

I have a drop ceiling in a rent home the needs replaced. The tiles interlock, as you put up on and   staple it in place, the next one slides into the grooves and you staple it and keep going. Well I had about 40 tiles up and now they are sagging? Any idea why? Any suggestions on what other method I can use other than staples?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a drop (suspended) ceiling, which usually involves metal track. What do you mean by "sagging"? Are the tiles deforming? Are the staples not holding? Please edit your question to clarify, and link a photo if possible.

Comment: if you can post a photo of the install as requested please show photo of the staples in the tiles.  It sounds possible your staples are penetrating to far into the tiles and pulling through.